# Add MDL tab programmatically

Tags: material-design-lite

I have a material design lite page using a tabbed layout that starts with a single tab. I have a menu action that adds an additional tab. JavaScript code adds the required <a> tag and content to the tab bar in the <header> and appends the related <section> and content <div> to the <main> tag.
The JavaScript code then calls the componentHandler.upgradeElement() function for the parent elements of the two additions.

Superficially this works and the new tab is displayed in the header and the new content <div> can be displayed by clicking the tab. However, clicking the original tab demonstrates that the "upgrade" was incomplete. The two elements in the tab bar are somewhat different and both have the "is-active" CSS class.

```
<div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar-container">
  <div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect is-casting-shadow mdl-js-ripple-effect--ignore-events" id="hdrTabs" data-upgraded=",MaterialRipple">
    <a href="#scroll-tab-1" class="mdl-layout__tab is-active">Checklists<span class="mdl-layout__tab-ripple-container mdl-js-ripple-effect" data-upgraded=",MaterialRipple"><span class="mdl-ripple is-animating" style="width: 1475.13px; height: 1475.13px; transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translate(349px, 31px);"></span></span></a>
    <a class="mdl-layout__tab is-active" href="#scroll-tab-2">New Checklist</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The two <section> elements are as they should be but the section related to the newly introduced tab does not have the display: none CSS attribute so the content is visible under the content of the original tab.

Is the only solution to manage clicks on the programmatically added tab from my own code base?

Answer (score 2):

There are two points to consider.

- upgradeElement  has to be called for an MDL component element. Which is in your case the div with class `mdl-js-tabs`. 
  Perhaps that is what you are doing (*The JavaScript code then calls the componentHandler.upgradeElement() function for the parent elements of the two additions*.)
- Because the div with `mdl-js-tabs` is already registered you need to call downgradeElements before calling upgradeElement.

Therefore something like the following should do:

```
var jstabs  = document.getElement /with mdl-js-tabs/;
componentHandler.downgradeElements(jstabs);
componentHandler.upgradeElement(jstabs);
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Not yet a complete solution but I am well aware that there may be other factors (bugs/complexity) on my page getting in the way. I will try a "clean" test page first and work from there.

Comment: Edit to above: I built a clean page but failed to properly activate a newly added tab. Interestingly, I then created a page with two original tabs, Then called .downgradeElements() on the tab bar and this had no effect upon the function of the two tabs. Perhaps the upgrade/downgrade functionality does not as yet include tab support? I will try replicating the MDL tab support from my own code (can't need much)

Comment: Sorry I don't get you. Here is a modified [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZaggg) which adds a tab via addtab function.

Comment: The official documentation states that you can only have one ‘is-active’ link & panel per tab bar. Maybe the fact that you have two, is causing a problem?